# What happened to civilians in Greece in the Balkan Wars

Tags: the-balkans

I have looked and found nothing about this. I need this for a history project about why someone immigrated from Greece (Amfissa, Delphi, Phocis). Any tips? Were they on rations? Was there a threat from invasions, etc... Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. It's 2am here, so a bit late to write an answer, but the paper [Violence and civilians during the Balkan Wars(1912–1913)](https://www.academia.edu/37187642/Violence_and_Civilians_During_the_Balkan_Wars_1912_1913_Journal_of_Balkan_and_Near_Eastern_Studies_Vol_20_no._6_2018_pp._547-563) may have the information you are looking for.

Comment: The regions mentioned in the question were quite far from the border by the time of the Balkan Wars; so I don't think @sempaiscuba's link explains things after all. The overall poverty of Greece at the time certainly does though; the 1910s were when the big wave of migration from Greece to the US started.